# The default height of the progress bar is too much

Tags: javascript, css

I am making a progress bar. I find the default `height` of the progress-bar of `bootstrap.js` is too much. So I try to reduce the `height` to `20%` as follows.

But it does not modify what I want. Does anyone know which attribute I should modify?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .progress-bar {
      height: 20%;
      line-height: 2px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Animated Progress Bar</h2>
  <p>The .active class animates the progress bar:</p>
  <div class="progress">
    <div id="abc" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/miduwu/4/edit?html,output)

Comment: What is happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the height of `.progress` - not `.progress-bar`:

```
.progress {
  height: 5px; /* needs to be an absolute measurement unless one of it's parent has an absolute height */
}
```

[Updated bin](http://jsbin.com/cuzatixeri/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1):

```
/* not .progress-bar */ 
.progress { 
      height: 10px;
      line-height: 2px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using external libraries to link bootstrap. So external will load after internal and take priority, sometimes takes priority over html styling too. You must use an accuratest selector like

```
div.container > div.progress > div#abc {/*  Styles That you want  */}
```